# Conan with cmake-conan missing conanbuild.conf

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I am want to package a CMake project with conan.
For that I use the following `conanfile.py`:

```py
import os
from conans import ConanFile, tools
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, CMakeToolchain
from conans.tools import Version

class BaseLibrary(ConanFile):
    name = "base-library"
    version = "1.0.0"
    description = """This is a test project with a library base::io
    and base::math and an executable cli."""
    license = "MIT"
    generators = "cmake_find_package_multi", "cmake_find_package",
    default_options = {"fmt:shared": True}
    build_policy = "missing"  # if this package is build by default if missing.
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    exports_sources = "*"

    _cmake = None

    def requirements(self):
        if Version(self.version) >= "1.0.0":
            self.requires("fmt/8.0.1")

    def _configure_cmake(self):
        if self._cmake:
            return self._cmake
        self._cmake = CMake(self)
        self._cmake.configure(source_folder=".")
        return self._cmake

    def build(self):
        cmake = self._configure_cmake()
        cmake.build()
        cmake.install()

    def package(self):
        cmake = self._configure_cmake()
        cmake.install()
        tools.rmdir(os.path.join(self.package_folder, "lib", "cmake"))
        tools.rmdir(os.path.join(self.package_folder, "lib", "pkgconfig"))
        tools.rmdir(os.path.join(self.package_folder, "share"))

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.names["cmake_find_package"] = "base"
        self.cpp_info.names["cmake_find_package_multi"] = "base"
        self.cpp_info.names["pkg_config"] = "base"
```

which is next to my main `CMakeLists.txt` file. The CMake project builds without problems and also has a proper `install` target which installs everything properly: `bin,lib,include,share`. In CMake I use the [conan-cmake](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan) module with basically something [like this](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan#using-conan_cmake_autodetect-and-conan_cmake_install-with-multi-configuration-generators).

When I run

```sh
conan create -s build_type=Release . demo/testing
```

I get the following weird error:

```sh
...
Requirements
    base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing from local cache - Cache
    fmt/8.0.1 from 'conancenter' - Cache
Packages
    base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing:4f2b14d304ab8e4391d162a6eb44110cc27a3faa - Build
    fmt/8.0.1:d4e9c4f02b4f03edf5a640dcd22779727d782e79 - Cache

Installing (downloading, building) binaries...
fmt/8.0.1: Already installed!
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: WARN: Build folder is dirty, removing it: /home/developer/.conan/data/base-library/1.0.0/demo/testing/build/4f2b14d304ab8e4391d162a6eb44110cc27a3faa
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: Configuring sources in /home/developer/.conan/data/base-library/1.0.0/demo/testing/source
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: Copying sources to build folder
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: Building your package in /home/developer/.conan/data/base-library/1.0.0/demo/testing/build/4f2b14d304ab8e4391d162a6eb44110cc27a3faa
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: Generator cmake_find_package created Findfmt.cmake
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: Generator cmake_find_package_multi created fmt-config-version.cmake
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: Generator cmake_find_package_multi created fmt-config.cmake
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: Generator cmake_find_package_multi created fmtTargets.cmake
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: Generator cmake_find_package_multi created fmtTarget-release.cmake
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: Aggregating env generators
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: Calling build()
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: 
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: ERROR: Package '4f2b14d304ab8e4391d162a6eb44110cc27a3faa' build failed
base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: WARN: Build folder /home/developer/.conan/data/base-library/1.0.0/demo/testing/build/4f2b14d304ab8e4391d162a6eb44110cc27a3faa
ERROR: base-library/1.0.0@demo/testing: Error in build() method, line 74
        cmake = self._configure_cmake()
while calling '_configure_cmake', line 65
        self._cmake = CMake(self)
        ConanException: The file /home/developer/.conan/data/base-library/1.0.0/demo/testing/build/4f2b14d304ab8e4391d162a6eb44110cc27a3faa/conanbuild.conf does not exist. Please, make sure that it was not generated in another folder.
```

What is the problem here and how can I resolve this? I could not find anything related to this?

Comment: See https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan#creating-packages

Comment: Ah thanks thats really enlightening.

my errors above where: I should have included `from conans import CMake` instead the one above (?) and should use [`CMakeToolchain()` ](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmaketoolchain.html?highlight=cmaketoolchain) to define a toolchain file.

Comment: One should use CMakeDeps and CMakeToolchain, which are the new ways which will be maintained in Conan V2..

Answer (score 0):

```py
from conans import ConanFile, CMake
...

def build(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    cmake.configure()
    cmake.build()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally found the issue:
The `CMake` you are importing is the one working with the `CMakeToolchain` which are both part of the `conan.tools.cmake` module.
The one that is described in the usage of `cmake_find_package`[[ref]](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_find_package_generator.html?highlight=cmake_find_package) is the one in `conans` module

So replacing:

```
from conans import ConanFile, tools
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, CMakeToolchain
```

by

```
from conans import ConanFile, tools, CMake
from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeToolchain
```

should fix your problem